# How to export a project in vs 2019?

Tags: python, visual-studio

I have created the project and I want to export the program to make it as an application so when I start in the desktop it opens the output of the program.

I tried to search for such an option in the vs (2019) but I didn't find it.I hope that you reply to me.

Comment: I want to compile my project into an application.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is too simply compile it with the Release Settings and then get the .exe from the Release Folder.

1. Go to `Solution Configurations`, this is the second Button to the left from the green Build button.
2. Select `Release` I guess currently `Debug` is selected.
3. Right-Click on the Solution in the Solution Explorer on the right and Select `open file in file exlporer` (pretty far down)
4. Go one folder up and go into the `Release` Folder
5. Copy your .exe and paste it somewhere and now you should be able to start it from everywhere.

If you compile it with the x64 Settings you have to go first into the x64 Folder and then there into the Release Folder.

You could also do the same with the Debug version, but the Release Option optimizes and it is literally named release.